# Communicating Non-UI data between View and Viewmodel

Tags: c#, mvvm, model, viewmodel

I'm working on an application for manual image processing and am using MVVM in C# to keep things organized and straightforward.

In the application, the user loads an image and then selects a region of the image to process by dragging 'handles' to set the corners of the analysis region. These handles are simply `Ellipse` objects contained within a `Canvas` that sits on top of the loaded image.

The viewmodel needs to be aware of the positions of the handles so that it can tell the model which pixels to analyze. This means that the viewmodel needs to know the coordinates of the handles relative to the upper-left-corner of the loaded image.

How can I communicate the positions of these handles to the viewmodel? Simply binding to `Canvas.Left` or `Canvas.Top` to obtain the positions of the handles is 1) Really, really ugly and 2) Not the information I need - I need the position relative to the image, not the containing canvas.

Thanks for any assistance!

If it helps, I'm instantiating my view model in the view (as I've been told to do) using

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <user:ImageProcessorViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you bind to the canvas' left and top property? That should be relative to the image (depending on your setup).